# Does System.IdentityModel allow the use of multiple client credential types on a single endpoint?

Tags: c#, wif, identity

In .NET 4.5, the Windows Identity Foundation classes from the namespace `Microsoft.IdentityModel` are now a part of the framework, and are found in `System.IdentityModel`. In this transition and upgrade, was the ability to support multiple types of client credentials (i.e. username/password or client certificate) on a single endpoint added? I have read in several places that this feature was on the table for inclusion at some point, but I have not found any way to enable this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well - that's the official description:

"Multiple Authentication Support
Support has been added to support multiple authentication modes, as supported by IIS, on a single WCF endpoint when using the HTTP transport and transport security. IIS allows you to enable multiple authentication modes on a virtual directory, this feature allows a single WCF endpoint to support the multiple authentication modes enabled for the virtual directory where the WCF service is hosted."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456789.aspx

Note that it say "HTTP transport and transport security" - so I guess you need to configure the auth methods at the IIS level and choose "InheritFromHost" on the binding in WCF config.